# How to reset transparency settings in Chrome menus/modals

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, chromium

I'm using a Windows 10 mod called Ghost Spectre and I'm struggling to find a way to reset Chrome menus and modals to their original, opaque look. Here are the examples:

[image]

[image]

How can I bring this transparency back to the default setting?

Comment: Have you looked for information on the software developer's site? That would be the first thing to try.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, without any luck, unfortunately.